# Dynamically cast types on pattern matching

Tags: rust, casting, traits

Suppose this:

```
pub fn handle_connection(&mut data: impl NetworkStream) {...}
```

where `NetworkStream`:

`pub trait NetworkStream`

So, I want to write, inside `handle_connection`, some generic code that is valid for dispatch an `HttpServer`, an `UdpServer` or a `WebsocketServer` custom types. The idea it's that the caller of `handle_connection` could pass any type that implements some trait (like NetworkStream, for example), implemented for those types, and `handle_connection` would be able to recognize, instanciate and call the correct type without knowing the incoming concrete type.

But, the main issue here is, how in Rust that piece of code is able to work with the `impl NetworkStream` argument and translate it to concrete code?

As note, I am asking for the idiomatic way of make a type casting based on some condition, like Java's `is instance of` operator, or for the proper way to do this kind of logic even if it's completly different of type checking and casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't differentiate inside of `handle_connection` which type it actually is. You have to move any type-specific code into the type-specific implementations of the trait.

Also, minor nitpick: `&mut data: impl NetworkStream` is a weird signature, it should probably be `data: &mut impl Networkstream`.

This is how such an architecture could look like. Of course all the types are dummy mocks and should be replaced with actual types. It's just to demonstrate how this would look like:

```
struct HttpServer {}
struct UdpServer {}
struct WebsocketServer {}

trait NetworkStream {
    fn receive_message(&mut self) -> String;
}

impl NetworkStream for HttpServer {
    fn receive_message(&mut self) -> String {
        "HttpMessage!".to_string()
    }
}
impl NetworkStream for UdpServer {
    fn receive_message(&mut self) -> String {
        "UdpMessage!".to_string()
    }
}
impl NetworkStream for WebsocketServer {
    fn receive_message(&mut self) -> String {
        "WebsocketMessage!".to_string()
    }
}

fn handle_connection(data: &mut impl NetworkStream) {
    let message = data.receive_message();
    println!("Received: {:?}", message);
}

fn main() {
    let mut http_server = HttpServer {};
    let mut udp_server = UdpServer {};
    let mut websocket_server = WebsocketServer {};
    handle_connection(&mut http_server);
    handle_connection(&mut udp_server);
    handle_connection(&mut websocket_server);
}
```

```
Received: "HttpMessage!"
Received: "UdpMessage!"
Received: "WebsocketMessage!"
```

---

To answer the second part of your question, there is *dynamic downcasting* with [`std::any::Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html). But unless it's absolutely necessary, I would try to find a code structure that does not require `Any`.

Usually, there is ways to resolve types statically, for example with the *visitor* pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I would like to know more about the idiomatic way of implementing the visitor pattern in Rust. Also, if its resolved at compile time, always better. Thanks in advice!

Comment: @AlexVergara Something along those lines: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=433fe8c39b4dfb0fbcac573dba3f6dae
Be aware that this is a more advanced pattern that is most likely way overkill for what you are trying to achieve. I just wanted to add it to show that there are ways to achieve static type resolution for traits. But stick to the [*KISS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle. Don't use advanced patterns if there are simpler solutions.

Comment: Wouldn't `&mut impl NetworkStream` be preferred to avoid dynamic dispatch? I don't see why a trait object would be necessary here.

Comment: @cdhowie If you think this is better :) fixed

Comment: Finally, what is the point over the initial signature vs the trait object one?

Comment: @Finomnis nice approach. Thanks for your time

Comment: @AlexVergara The `impl` actually generates a new method into the binary that represents each type. `dyn` only generates one method and then uses runtime dispatching. The advantages are that `impl` are generally a bit faster, but the binary becomes a little bigger. (That's at least my understanding)

Comment: Sounds resonable. I suppose that `impl` monomorphizes the known elements at compile time, and dyn uses dynamic dispatch, what may cause to slow down your code. My guess is that with the known code of the example, the lookage to the vtable to find the right type it's despreciable

Comment: @Finomnis It can cause the binary to become bigger. In this trivial example, the size of the vtables for the `dyn` version probably exceeds the size of the additional generated code for the `impl` version, so the `dyn` version could very well wind up being larger!

Comment: @cdhowie and also with the extra cost of the dynamic dispatch, even if its minimal on modern arquitechtures